# How to search within message body for specific tracked message in Biztalk 

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2009

In Biztalk 2009, I can view the 'Tracked Message Events' from the admin console. I need to find a particular message (containing a particular string in the body) for which I know the day of arrival, but not the time.

How can I easily go about this?
If I could right click and 'Save to file' on all messages, I could then use grep to find out the message. However, you can only do this on one message at a time, and I have 5188 messages for this day (so this is not practical).
If there was some way to enter the message criteria in the tracked message events dialog, I could easily do it, but I don't believe Biztalk 2009 supports this.

Is there a way to get this information directly from the Biztalk database tables using a SQL script, or is there another easy way to do this that I am not aware of?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of I then assume that you also have the tracking of messages activated? As you probably know BizTalk actually only saves the message body if tracking has been activated on the ports or in the orchestration that messages passes thru.

But if tracking has been activated the message body is first saved in the BizTalk MessageBox and then moved by the tracking agent to the DTA database in BizTalk - as described in detail [here](http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2009/11/20/insight-into-biztalk-server-message-tracking/). Within the DTA database the message body is saved in a compress format and there isn't really a good way to search the whole body for a specific value.

One way could be to use on of [these methods](http://connectedthoughts.wordpress.com/2008/04/02/3-ways-of-programatically-extracting-a-message-body-from-the-biztalk-tracking-database/) to extract the messages and then use some other way of searching the messages once on file for example.

Howevere if possible I would then in the future recommend you to promote the values you'd like to search for. That would force the values to be stored in sperepare fields in the DTA databse and make them searchable.

Comment: Thanks very much Riri - I ended up using the first method mentioned in that link (Biztalk object model) and modifying the code to work on a list of GUID's, instead of just one. This meant I could add the column to my HAT results 'MessageInstanceID', copy the results returned in HAT, pull the GUID's into a list, and extract them using that code mentioned. I'll look into promoting some of the properties to help searches out in future as well.